# Call a higher order F# function from C#

Tags: c#, f#, delegates

Given the F# higher order function (taking a function in parameter):

```
let ApplyOn2 (f:int->int) = f(2)
```

and the C# function

```
public static int Increment(int a) { return a++; }
```

How do I call `ApplyOn2` with `Increment` as parameter (from C#)?
Note that `ApplyOn2`  is exported as `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int,int>` which do not match with `Increment`'s signature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you would like to provide a more friendly interop experience, consider using the System.Func delegate type directly in F#:

```
let ApplyOn2 (f : System.Func<int, int>) = f.Invoke(2)
```

You would be able to call your F# function very easily in C# like this:

```
MyFSharpModule.ApplyOn2(Increment); // 3
```

There is an issue with the Increment function as you have written it, however. You need the prefix form of the increment operator in order for your function to return the correct result:

```
public static int Increment(int a) { return ++a; }
```

Answer (score 31):

To get an FSharpFunc from the equivalent C# function use:

```
Func<int,int> cs_func = (i) => ++i;
var fsharp_func = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int,int>.FromConverter(
    new Converter<int,int>(cs_func));
```

To get a C# function from the equivalent FSharpFunc, use

```
var cs_func = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int,int>.ToConverter(fsharp_func);
int i = cs_func(2);
```

So, this particular case, your code might look like:

```
Func<int, int> cs_func = (int i) => ++i;
int result = ApplyOn22(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int, int>.FromConverter(
            new Converter<int, int>(cs_func)));
```

Comment: Is there an example for a function that has two parameters?

Comment: @ScottNimrod take a look at this, it has examples how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/jaredpar/converting-system-funct1-tn-to-fsharpfuncttresult (F# uses the curried version of the function)

Answer (score -3):

Just create reference to your assembly:

```
#r @"Path\To\Your\Library.dll"
let ApplyOn2 (f:int->int) = f(2)
ApplyOn2 Library.Class.Increment
```

Comment: The problem is not on referencing assemblies.
The problem is that ApplyOn2 is exported as Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int,int> which do not match with Increment.

Comment: I've tried it and it works:

> ClassLibrary1.Class1.Increment;;
Binding session to 'J:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll'...
val it : int -> int = <fun:clo@0>

> let ApplyOn2 (f:int->int) = f(2);;
val ApplyOn2 : (int -> int) -> int

> ApplyOn2 ClassLibrary1.Class1.Increment;;
val it : int = 2

Comment: @ssp: This is an example of calling C# from F#. F# is much more forgiving about function and delegate type conversion as you point out, however, the question is about calling F# from C#.