# How do I assign a multi-parameter F# function to a C# variable?

Tags: f#

I have the following F# function:

```
let myFSharpFunction : IO.TryTransform<IDatabaseService,EditForm,SyncType,ErrorDescription> =
    fun _ _ -> Ok someValue
```

I would like to use this F# function as a value/delegate in my C# code:

```
FSharpFunc<IDatabaseService, FSharpFunc<EditForm, FSharpResult<SyncType, ErrorDescription>>> referenceToFSharpFunction  = myFSharpFunction;
```

However, I get an error:

> Error CS0428  Cannot convert method group 'myFSharpFunction' to
>   non-delegate type 'FSharpFunc>>'. Did you intend to invoke the
>   method?

I then tried:

```
public delegate FSharpResult<SyncType, ErrorDescription> myDelegate(IDatabaseService database, EditForm editForm);
...
myDelegate someDelegate = myFSharpFunction;
FSharpFunc<IDatabaseService, FSharpFunc<EditForm, FSharpResult<SyncType, ErrorDescription>>> FSharpFuncToInvoke = someDelegate;
```

However, this attempt also gave me an error:

> type 'Sevan.Android.FormsSyncFragment.myDelegate' to
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc>>'

**Update:**

***Attempt 1:***

I then tried adding the following function to an F# module:

```
let toFunc2 f = Func<_, _, _> f // f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

I next updated the C# code to the following:

```
var referenceToFSharpFunction = toFunc2<IDatabaseService, EditForm, FSharpResult<SyncType, ErrorDescription>>(myFSharpFunction);
```

But I then received this error:

> Cannot convert method group 'FSharpFuncToInvoke' to non-delegate type
>   'FSharpFunc>>'. Did you intend to invoke
>   the method?

***Attempt 2:***

I also tried setting the F# code to the following:

```
let toFunc2 f = Func<IDatabaseService,EditForm, Result<SyncType,ErrorDescription>> f // f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

Then within my C#, I attempted this:

```
var referenceToFSharpFunction = toFunc2<IDatabaseService, EditForm, FSharpResult<SyncType, ErrorDescription>>(myFSharpFunctione);
```

But that attempt gave me this error:

> Error CS0308  The non-generic method
>   'Mock.toFunc2(FSharpFunc>>)' cannot be used with type arguments

In conclusion, how do I assign a multi-parameter F# function to a C# variable?

Comment: What is the definition of `IO.TryTransform`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are defining some F# functionality that should be used by a C# client, then I would strongly recommend exposing all the functionality in a C#-friendly way - that means, doing all the wrapping on the F# side, so that the C# consumer does not have to worry about things like `FSharpFunc` at all.

It's a bit hard to say how this should work in your case - because your example does not actually show any realistic piece of code - only some kind of adapter with a fairly complex interface - but you could do something along the following lines:

```
// Your F# function that is used elsewhere in F# code
let myFsharpFunction = 
  fun _ _ -> Ok someValue

// Your F# logic, exposed as a C#-friendly `System.Func` delegate
let myCsharpFunction = 
  System.Func<_, _, _>(myFsharpFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I now receive a warning FS0040 using the example that was provided that I haven't figured out how to resolve.

Comment: @ScottNimrod You'll need to post a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the issue - otherwise, it's difficult to say what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The F# function type `FSharpFunc` is something completely separate from the `Func`/`Action` used in C#, so you need to "convert" it by creating the respective type that C# understands, which is easy, but needs to be done for each number of arguments individually.

```ml
let toFunc1 f = Func<_, _> f // f : 'a -> 'b
let toFunc2 f = Func<_, _, _> f // f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c
// etc.

let toAction0 f = Action f // f : unit -> unit
let toAction1 f = Action<_> f // f : 'a -> unit
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this. However, I'm still spinning my wheels. I did update my question with my latest attempt to implement your suggestion.

Comment: These conversion functions were intended to be used from F#, where they are automatically generic. Apparently, there's actually a built-in way that can be used from C# as well; it's just rather verbose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952393/236507